# adding a conditions in for loop

Tags: vba, loops

I have the following two functions in VBA. And my excel would look like this.

```
OddsId  Agt      Ma   Sma     Result
1       Agt1    Ma1   Sma1     x
```

My intentions is to calculate the value of x. And i want to add a condition like, User can provide only one value at a time among Agt, ma and Sma. If any of these 2 fields are non-zero then my result should read "Error". I am not sure where to add this condition in these functions.

I am also not pretty sure what would If NOT function would actually return !!
Kindly help me on this.

```
Function fcComm1(oddsId As Integer, agt As String, ma As String, sma As String, fcOption1 As Integer)
If Not setFcType(agt, ma, sma) Then
    fcComm1 = "Invalid2"
    Return
End If
For i = 1 To bets.ListRows.Count
    currOddsId = bets.ListColumns("OddsId").DataBodyRange(i)
    currTransId = bets.ListColumns("TransId").DataBodyRange(i)
    currPlayer = bets.ListColumns("Account").DataBodyRange(i)

    If (currOddsId = oddsId) Then
        If FcType = "agt" Then
            currAgt = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(currPlayer, accounts.DataBodyRange, 9, False)
            If (agt <> currAgt) Then
                fcComm1 = ""
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
        ElseIf FcType = "ma" Then
            currMa = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(currPlayer, accounts.DataBodyRange, 10, False)
            If (ma <> currMa) Then
            fcComm1 = ""
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
        ElseIf FcType = "sma" Then
            currSma = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(currPlayer, accounts.DataBodyRange, 11, False)
            If (sma <> currSma) Then
            fcComm1 = ""
                GoTo NextIteration
            End If
        End If


        exchangeRate = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(currPlayer, accounts.DataBodyRange, 4, False)
        blindRisk = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(currPlayer, accounts.DataBodyRange, 6, False) / 100#
        fcComm1 = fcComm1 + ForecastBet(currTransId, exchangeRate, blindRisk)

NextIteration:

    End If
Next
End Function



Function setFcType(agt As String, ma As String, sma As String)
setFcType = True

If Len(agt) + Len(ma) + Len(sma) = 0 Then
    FcType = "company"
ElseIf agt <> "" And agt <> "0" Then
    FcType = "agt"
ElseIf ma <> "" And ma <> "0" Then
    FcType = "ma"
ElseIf sma <> "" And sma <> "0" Then
    FcType = "sma"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Note: All the variables are defined correctly, though i hve deleted those while pasting the code here. Currently this code is working fine. I would jus need to add someconditions. Thnks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a corrected version of your `setFcType` function returning false in case of having more than one variable different than "".

```
Function setFcType(agt As String, ma As String, sma As String)
setFcType = True

If ((Len(Trim(agt)) > 0 And (Len(Trim(ma)) > 0 Or Len(Trim(sma)) > 0)) Or (Len(Trim(ma)) > 0 And (Len(Trim(agt)) > 0 Or Len(Trim(sma)) > 0))) Then
    setFcType = False
    Exit Function
End If

If Len(agt) + Len(ma) + Len(sma) = 0 Then
    FcType = "company"
ElseIf agt <> "" And agt <> "0" Then
    FcType = "agt"
ElseIf ma <> "" And ma <> "0" Then
    FcType = "ma"
ElseIf sma <> "" And sma <> "0" Then
    FcType = "sma"
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much @varocarbas. It helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Your description and code were crytal clear (what is not always the case...).